# Tsql Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Tags: sql-server

With this code I got this error:

> "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int"

```
declare
    @StrSql nvarchar(max),
    @TableName nvarchar(50),
    @Month datetime
set
    @TableName = 'dbo.OneTransfer'
set
    @month ='2016-02-02'
set
    @StrSql ='select * from ' + @TableName + ' where OperateDate >=' + CONVERT(char(10),@Month,20)
execute (@StrSql)
```

This is my SQL table:

[image]

Comment: Don't write such code. Use parameterized queries. Concatenating strings exposes you to SQL injection attacks, conversion errors like this one *and* prevents you from passing Unicode data - like Chinese characters. Use `select * from my table where OperateDate>=@date` and use `sp_executesql to pass the date parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your error:

```
set @StrSql ='select * from ' + @TableName + ' where OperateDate >=' + CONVERT(char(10),@Month,20)
```

Try to print it out, it will show you UNQUOTED date string

```
where OperateDate >= 2016-02-02
```

So it's `OperateDate >= 2016` to cause the error.

What you need instead is to QUOTEyour date string:

```
set @StrSql ='select * from ' + @TableName + ' where OperateDate >=' + quotename(CONVERT(char(10),@Month,20), '''')
```

Comment: Thanks your time. It's work. Very clear. I really appreciate.